# How can I iterate over the characters of strings within an array?

Tags: c, string, loops

I want to print each characters of the strings belonging to an array of strings.

The first part of the code is: take as input an integer, and create an array of that size. Then add n words to fill the array (so I get an array of strings).

Here's my idea

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
char *a[n];
a[n] = malloc(n*sizeof(char));

int i;
int j;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    a[i] = malloc(sizeof(char));

    }


for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    printf("write the words: ");
    scanf("%s", a[i]);

    }

//till this point everything works  

//now I need to print each character of the strings

for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    for ( j = 0; j < strlen(a[i][j]); j++) {

        printf("%s", a[i][j]);

        }

    }
```

I get this warning:

> format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]

on this line:

```
printf("%s", a[i][j])`;
```

If I execute, after typing the words, I get segmentation fault. I don't get the problems with the two for loops.

Comment: `a[n] = ...;` UB and `malloc(sizeof(char))` ..1 length `char` array.

Comment: `printf("%s", a[i][j])`-->`printf("%c", a[i][j])`

Comment: Your program is wrong on several account. `a[n] = malloc(n*sizeof(char));` if you want to hold char pointers in array you should allocate for pointers and not char. This allocation is main reason of problem among others.

Comment: `a[n] = malloc(n*sizeof(char));` --> `a = malloc(sizeof *a * n);`

Answer (score 2):

Lets start line by line.

**Line 1** is wrong,  it should be `size_t n`  (which means `long unsigned int`) and not `int n`, please read more about [MALLOC](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm).

**Next line** with problems:

```
a[n] = malloc(n*sizeof(char));
```

This means that, if `n == 2`, then you have:

```
a[2] = malloc(n*sizeof(char));
```

and you access that ARRAY out of bounds, the line should be:

```
a = malloc(n*sizeof(char));
```

but here is another thing, The standard guaranties that `sizeof(char)` is at least `1` so this line:

```
a = malloc(n*sizeof(char));
```

is the same like this line:

```
a = malloc( n * 1 );
```

**Next problem**:

```
int i;
int j;
```

Should be:

```
size_t i;
size_t j;
```

Why? Well because once that you realize that `malloc` expects `size_t` then you should know that in that LOOP the comparison between `signed` and `unsigend` is not what you need.

**Next problem**:

```
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for ( j = 0; j < strlen(a[i][j]); j++) {
        printf("%s", a[i][j]);

    }
}
```

Here you have more problems:
`strlen(a[i][j])` should be `strlen( a[i]`

**And this Line**:

```
printf("%s\n", a[i][j]);
```

**Should be**:

```
printf("%c\n", a[i][j]);
```

**Things which you should also take care are**:

- always check `scanf` for errors.
- the length of those strings very important to be known.
- do not forget to `free` what you `malloc`.

**After you put all together you'll get**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( void ){
    size_t n;

    if ( scanf("%zu", &n) != 1 ){
        printf("Error,scanf\n");
    }

    char *a[n];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        a[i] = malloc( 256 );
        if ( a[i] == NULL ){
            printf("Error, malloc\n");
            for ( size_t k = 0 ; k < i ; k++ ){
                free( a[k] );
            }
            return 1;
        }
    }


    for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
        printf("write the words: ");
        if ( scanf("%255s", a[i]) != 1 ){
            printf("Error, scanf\n");
            for ( size_t k = 0 ; k < n ; k++ ){
                free( a[k] );
            }
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
        for ( size_t j = 0 ; j < strlen( a[i] ) ; j++ ) {
            printf("%c\n", a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for ( size_t k = 0 ; k < n ; k++ ){
        free( a[k] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if you are planning to use a VLA of pointers to dynamical allocated arrays of the same size (256), you can just declare `char a[n][256];`.

Comment: @Bob__ True, but we do not know what OP needs, because the OP it self is not sure about what he needs.

Comment: @Bob__ The fist line, `a[n] = malloc(n*sizeof(char));` should not exist in he's code at all. Of couse that `a[n]` is a type of `char*` because he declared it as `char *a[n];`. I tried to illustrate the difference only. I removed that part, to not create confusion.

Comment: Again, I agree ;) You simply didn't mentioned it.